# Position image inside and behind a background image

Tags: html, css

I'm planning to position some images in a circle background image but it doesn't seem to work well.
My goal is to center these images behind and inside the circle.

Any help?

```css
div.info_image {
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    background: url("http://japancrystal.altervista.org/themes/crystal/imgs/colonna_sx/cerchio_descrizioneluogo.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 220px;
    width: 100%;
}

img.img_place{
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 155px;
    height: 155px;
      margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="info_image">
<img src="http://japancrystal.altervista.org/themes/crystal/imgs/locations/ingresso.png" class="img_place">
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Kleper_galaxy/wpfbyL5g/8/)

[RESULT DEMO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nihcD.png)

Comment: Why you don't use a unique image?

Comment: because images change dynamically (MySql).

Comment: In your example there is 2 images... i'll suppose you can use position absolute and z-index....

Comment: Yeah! In my example "info_image" div remains the same. What is changed (and I need to center and put behind) is the image img_place

Comment: Is it just for me that the images are blocked? Firefox claimed `Content Security Policy: Upgrading insecure request ‘http://japancrystal.altervista.org/themes/crystal/imgs/colonna_sx/cerchio_descrizioneluogo.png’ to use ‘https’`

Comment: Fixed! Now you should see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this code to your img_place class :

```
img.img_place {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
div.info_image {
    position: relative;
    background: url(http://japancrystal.altervista.org/themes/crystal/imgs/colonna_sx/cerchio_descrizioneluogo.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 220px;
}

img.img_place {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% + 3px);
    left: calc(50% + 7px);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 173px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: grid` to place them on top of each other.

Because the "ring" image isn't placed with the circle in the middle, I had to use `transform: translate` to move it, which changed the stacking order too. That's why there is a `z-index` of -1 on the city image.

For some reason, `justify-content: center` and `align-items: center` on `.info_image` didn't work as well as using `self-justify` and `self-align` on the images.

```css
div.info_image {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "stacked";
  height: 220px;
  width: 100%;
}

.info_image > img {
  --img-size: 155px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  grid-area: stacked;
  width: var(--img-size);
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.info_image > .city {
  --img-size: 110px;
  transform: translate(5px, 2px);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="info_image">
  <img class="city" src="https://japancrystal.altervista.org/themes/crystal/imgs/locations/ingresso.png" />
  <img src="https://japancrystal.altervista.org/themes/crystal/imgs/colonna_sx/cerchio_descrizioneluogo.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```css
div.info_image {
  border: none;
  background: url("http://japancrystal.altervista.org/themes/crystal/imgs/colonna_sx/cerchio_descrizioneluogo.png") no-repeat center center;
  height: 220px;
  width: 244px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

img.img_place {
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 173px;
  height: 173px;
  transform: translate(8px, 3px);
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="info_image">
  <img src="http://japancrystal.altervista.org/themes/crystal/imgs/locations/ingresso.png" class="img_place">
</div>
```

Not sure why your images don't show in snippet, but they do in this fiddle...

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bgakz3vq/1/)